# How to Process PayPal Subscription Refund With API?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

After proceeding with the subscription to Sandbox, the data below will be answered.

```
orderID:3MA30854KN5622241
subscriptionID:I-E1DY12BAWXD1
```

With the above information, it is possible to suspend the subscription, but it does not appear to be refundable for the subscription.

API
[https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/{id}](https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/%7Bid%7D)

I checked if there was any information if I searched for subscription information, but I couldn't find a way to process a subscription refund in the response value, so I'm asking for your help.

If a refund is originally impossible, I would appreciate it if you could let me know that it is impossible.
Thank you.

How to handle PayPal subscription cancellation and refund processing with API

Comment: Where exactly is `3MA30854KN5622241` from? Show the precise location and time you obtained this.

Comment: "npmi @paypal/react-paypal-js" response..

Answer (score 0):

Here is what should work...

Query transactions on the profile with the [List transactions for subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_transactions) API. Note that start_time and end_time are required query string parameters , e.g. as per the sample

> https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-BW452GLLEP1G/transactions?start_time=2018-01-21T07:50:20.940Z&end_time=2018-08-21T07:50:20.940Z

The response will have transaction IDs (which are *not* order IDs)

Transaction IDs are the same as captures or sales, and should be usable with one of the refund API operations...

- v2: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_refund
- older v1: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#sale_refund